# PHP rewrite url in htaccess have to point other url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite some url by using .htaccess rewrite

I have url something like this:

`domain.com/index?/pid=10550`

and want to rewrite users to
`domain.com/index.php?pid=10550`

So, what will happen is users will access that url in backend

I'm new to php and have read some blogs like this have no luck

Also, I have tried this

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^domain.com/index?/$ /domain.com/index.php? [L]
```

it says The page isn't redirecting properly
and some times shows me a directory

Answer (score 0):

You can not match against querystring in  RewriteRule's pattern. You will have to match against `{THE_REQUEST}` variable (a full request line sent by a client to the server) using a RewriteCond

```
RewriteEngine on
#Remove .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
#redirect /index.php/?pid=123 to /index.php?pid=123 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php/\?pid=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index?pid=%1 [L,R]
```

This will redirect `/index.php/?pid=123` to `/index.php?pid=123` .

Comment: Is possible to remove the .php extension in that url?

Comment: Please be specific. Do you want to remove .php from the requested uri?

Comment: yes. I need to remove .php extension also
RewriteRule ^ /index.php?pid=%1 [L,R]

Comment: For eg :
RewriteRule ^ /index?pid=%1 [L,R]

Comment: I am getting this error
The page isn't redirecting properly

Comment: Are there any other rules?

Comment: No.There is no any other rules

Comment: In my url I add index.php its working fine but i remove .php and run , it showing me as an the page isn't redirecting properly error